# Converting Array of Strings to Array of Floats

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, floating-point

I'm writing an app that revolves around getting sets of numerical data from a file. However, since the data is acquired in string form, I have to convert it to floats, which is where the fun starts. The relevant section of my code is as shown (lines 65-73):

```
    ft = []
    puts "File Name: #{ARGV[0]}"
    File.open(ARGV[0], "r") do |file|
        file.each_line do |line|
            ft << line.scan(/\d+/)
        end
    end

ft.collect! {|i| i.to_f}
```

This works just fine in irb, that is, the last line changes the array to floats.

```
irb(main):001:0> ft = ["10", "23", "45"]
=> ["10", "23", "45"]
irb(main):002:0> ft.collect! {|i| i.to_f}
=> [10.0, 23.0, 45.0]
```

However when I run my application I get this error:

```
ruby-statistics.rb:73:in `block in <main>': undefined method `to_f' for #<Array:
0x50832c> (NoMethodError)
        from ruby-statistics.rb:73:in `collect!'
        from ruby-statistics.rb:73:in `<main>'
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

`line.scan` returns an array, so you are inserting an array into an array. The easiest thing to do would be to call `flatten` on the array before you convert the strings to floats.

```
ft = []
puts "File Name: #{ARGV[0]}"
File.open(ARGV[0], "r") do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
            ft << line.scan(/\d+/)
    end
end

ft = ft.flatten.collect { |i| i.to_f }
```

Answer (score 6):

You should have a look at the format of "ft" after reading the file.

Each line gets stored in another array so in fact "ft" looks something like this:

```
[["1","2"],["3","4"]]
```

So you have to do something like this:

```
ft = []
puts "File Name: #{ARGV[0]}"
File.open(ARGV[0], "r") do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
            ft << line.scan(/\d+/)
    end
end

tmp = []

ft.each do |line|
    line.each do |number|
        tmp << number.to_f
    end
end

puts tmp
```

This is just a guess since I don't know what your file format looks like.

Edit:

Here as a one-liner:

```
ft.flatten!.collect! { |i| i.to_f }
```

Comment: also don't forget you can use .inspect to examine ft:  puts ft.inspect