# How to set a specific value to a string after fetched from database?

Tags: ruby

I am facing a problem where I can't think anything about what I want to implement on my system!

I want to share here with my concept/scenario if I can get help from this platform and I am sure I can get help if I can clarify the scenario because there are many great developers.

Look for example, here are an array like below

```
ary = ["a","a", "a", "a"] // coming from database
```

If I loop and print then I can get 4 `a` string but I want to assign on every `a` some value like `0.5`, which means it will be like below

```
ary = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

then want to `sum` of that like `2.0` or any other based on data count.

I don't know if I wrong or stupid question but I think if there is a concept then there is a solution must be.

Please don't rush just let me know if the question wrong for this platform then I can remove this on my own.

TIA

Comment: https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/ruby-map-method/ - #map

Comment: I understand that you want to replace `"a"` in the array with `0.5`. Is it possible that there will be other values returned from the database? Or a different number of elements, like `["a", "b", "c"]`? What do you want to do then?

Comment: @spickermann no possibilities for other values only same values but more than thousands.

Comment: So there can only be `a`'s returned but the number might differ. Okay. Why don't you just count the number of `a`'s and multiple the number with `0.5`.?That is certainly faster than returning thousands of records from the database and not use them later on. How does your database query look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Array of Strings to Array of Floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927242/converting-array-of-strings-to-array-of-floats)